# Prove by induction a relationship between sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations

I'm grappling with this problem:

A sequence is defined as $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ where $b_1 = 2, b_2 = 1$ for all n≥3.

Prove (using mathematical induction) that the relationship between the two sequences can be described as $b_n = f_n + f_{n-2}$ for all n≥3.

($f$ represents the fibonacci sequence, which is recursively defined as

$f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}, f_1 = 1, f_2 = 1$ for all n≥3)

The base case should be when n=3,
but I'm unsure of how to set up the inductive step.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you mean $b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$ and is $f_n$ the Fibonacci sequence (and precise definition even of this is required) - you do need to take care with writing questions which are precise and don't require us to make assumptions. You should also give a sense of what you know about induction - have you any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I understand inductive proofs require two items to be proven: the base case (which shouldn't be hard) and the inductive case (k+1 when k is some value set equal to n and assumed to be true)

I'm guessing the hypothesis would look like

$b_k = f_k + f_{k-2}$

  My best stab at beginning the proof would be to create the following statement:
$b_{k+1} = f_{k+1} + f{k-1}$ 
and try to substitute in known values from the Fibonacci sequence, but I gas out here.

Comment: I would say the base cases are $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: @CompSciStudent The inductive step begins with assuming that the statement you wish to prove is true for $n$ and shows this implies that it is true for $n+1$. The base case gives a foundation, You should start by stating the (assumed) true statement for $n$. What would then be the statement for $n+1$

Comment: I believe that I've done that in the comment above.

Abandoning the naming convention of using k,

the assumption should be $b_n = f_n + f_{n-2}$

and the statement for $n + 1$ would be
$b_{n+1} = f_{n+1} + f_{n-1}$

I could very well be wrong though.

Comment: Continuing this, you can rewrite $b_{n-1} = f_{(n-1)}+f_{(n-1)-2}$.  i.e. Just plug in $(n-1)$ and $(n-2)$ in the subscripts.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you for the help